# How do I draw North-South, East-West, Northeast-Southwest, and Northwest-Southeast lines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing, polyline-creation

Is there a way to draw four line segments through a point that extend in 8 directions based on my coordinate system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [editor tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m500000002000000) you could use the direction, deflection and length functions when drawing a line. If its just the four lines this should get you out of trouble. This [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/and_a_length/01m700000047000000/) has some background information about creating a segment using an angle and length. This [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000003z000000) has some information about Arcgis and direction measuring systems. Hope this helps.